# Do << to string

Tags: python

So I am trying to find the first N bits of a string in python but it always returns
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'str' and 'int'`

Here is my code:

```
def firstBits(num, count):
    return bin(num)[2:] << count
```

Comment: Why not just slice again?

Comment: `bin()` returns a string, not a number (that's why you're able to slice it). You need to convert it back to an `int` to use bitwise operations.

Comment: What are first three bits of the `"ÅÆØ"` string supposed to be?

Comment: You need to show sample input and expected output. Your stated requirements are ambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `f-string`, you can convert show the binary representation of `num` using the `b` formatter (b for binary). Then you cut the first `count` char of this representation, which correspond to the first `count` bits.

```py
def firstBits(num, count):
    return f'{num:b}'[:count]
```

optionally, you can convert it back to an interger

```py
def firstBits(num, count):
    return int(f'{num:b}'[:count])
```

Answer (score 0):

`bin(num)` returns a string, and it's still a string after slicing. You need to convert it back to an `int` before shifting.

```
def firstBits(num, count):
    return int(bin(num)[2:], 2) << count
```

This will fix the error, but either I don't understand what you want to do or the algorithm is incorrect. I don't see how removing the first 2 bits and then shifting will get you the first N bits.

Comment: do you know how I could do it to base 2 integers?

Comment: That's what this does. `bin()` converts to base 2. E.g. `bin(9)` is `'1001'`

Comment: but it converts it back to a normal int right? Isn't that what the extra 2 does?

Comment: Right. If you want that in binary you can use `bin()` again.